# preventDefault and pass parameter for click event listener

Tags: javascript, html

I want to stop the submit event for a button, but also pass a parameter into a function that is triggered from the click. Here's what I thought could work:

```
function NL(line, event){
  event.preventDefault();
  document.getElementsByClassName('new-line')[1].innerHTML=line;
}
document.getElementsByClassName('new-line')[0].addEventListener('click', function(){NL('add new line');});
```

Here's the HTML:

```
<form class='myform'>
  <div class='form-block'>
    <span class='line'>1</span>
    <button class='new-line'>New Line</button>
    <button class='new-line'>New 2nd Line</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

I can't change the HTML, I can only edit the JS. Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function accepts two parameters `function NL(line, event){...}` but you're calling it with only one parameter `NL('add new line');`.

You're not sending the event to the NL function.

This should work:

```
function NL(line, event){
    event.preventDefault();
    document.getElementsByClassName('new-line')[1].innerHTML=line;
}
document.getElementsByClassName('new-line')[0].addEventListener('click', function(event){
    NL('add new line', event);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
function NL(line, event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  document.getElementsByClassName('new-line')[1].innerHTML = line;
}
document.getElementsByClassName('new-line')[0].addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  NL('add new line', event);
});
```

```html
<form class='myform'>
  <div class='form-block'>
    <span class='line'>1</span>
    <button class='new-line'>New Line</button>
    <button class='new-line'>New 2nd Line</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: You are the best! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Declare the `event` with `addEventlistener()`

```js
function NL(line, event){
  event.preventDefault();
  document.getElementsByClassName('new-line')[1].innerHTML=line;
}
document.getElementsByClassName('new-line')[0].addEventListener('click', function(){NL('add new line',event);});
```

```html
Here's the HTML:

<form class='myform'>
  <div class='form-block'>
    <span class='line'>1</span>
    <button class='new-line'>New Line</button>
    <button class='new-line'>New 2nd Line</button>
  </div>
</form>
```